# Parallel Data processing: I want to make python use the GPU for data processing?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, parallel-processing

Is it possible to make python use the `GPU` for data processing?

I know that for a library to use the `GPU`, it should support `CUDA` but it doesn't if I asked about other options to make faster to process the data.

Take as an example the typical library for DP: `Pandas`

To make it simple to understand: I want to use GPU for my data processing when using pandas. How can I do it?

Thank you,

Comment: cuDF library, part of [Rapids](https://rapids.ai/), provides pandas-like functionality on the GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to find a library that supports GPU data processing in Python, but doesn't use CUDA for that. Well, CUDA is a widely popular standard for utilizing parallel processing on a GPU and (at least as I know) all leading platforms for DP stick to the standards, so implementations of their algorithms is based on CUDA.

So, if you really want to avoid CUDA, and you even success to find a Python lib that will give you an API for GPU multiprocessing (by wrapping some C/C++ libs), you will have to spend much time on coding all DP stuff that you need to work with.